# Is there a good addon that will inform me when my poisons are going to expire?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've just started levelling up a rogue and I keep missing when my poisons end.

Is there a decent addon for warning me when they're about to run out, or when I have none applied?

I'm looking for something with an audible warning, screen flash and/or message in the middle of my screen.  I play on a 30" monitor and the buff icons are quite often out of my field of view.

I had a look around on Curse but the ones I found don't seem to have been updated in a while, like [Cyanide Poison Reminder](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/cyanide-poison-reminder) but has been updated for 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Poisoner](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/poisoner)?  It seems to do what you're after:

- warns you when your poisons are about to expire
- warns you when you're low on poisons and need to restock

Comment: Aha!  I did look at Poisoner, but that functionality wasn't immediately visible on the Curse page.  I thought it was just an addon for applying poisons.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you don't need an add-on for what you need.

If you haven't modified your in-game GUI in the upper right corner, left of map, you have your buffs. There you have your poisons with the weapons you applied them to and the minutes remaining until they expire.

Comment: Yeah, but I quite often don't realise they're run out until after the boss fight, or another player's just killed me.  What I'm looking for is something like PallyPower, but for rogues, that'll display a warning of some sort saying "No poisons applied!".  Maybe an audible ding or screen flash.

Comment: I added some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the normal buff trackers will handle poisons (and other weapon enchants).  Personally, I end up using [ZOMGBuffs](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/zomgbuffs) since I'm an altaholic and it tracks most of my short and long term buffs on all my toons.